# ICommand CanExecute gets invoked, even after the ViewModel got removed from UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

CommmandManager invokes the CanExecuteChanged event, event if the button, which binds to this ICommand, disappears from the UI

**CommandHandler**

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{

    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public CommandHandler(Action action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute != null)
        {
            return _canExecute();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

**View**
In the view, i'm binding to a list of viewmodels (for calls)
Note: on the UI there is no problem, the Binding works correctly.
(also for multiple calls)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CallHandlingViewModels}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <local:CallHandlingControl />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**ViewModel CallHandlingViewModel**

```
public class CallHandlingViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    private ICallHandlingModel _model;

    public CommandHandler AnswerCommand { get; }
    public CommandHandler EndCommand { get; }

    public CallHandlingViewModel(IDispatcher dispatcher, ICallHandlingModel model, BsCallEventArgs data) : base(model)
    {
        Dispatcher = dispatcher;

        _model = model;

        AnswerCommand = new CommandHandler(() => _model.AnswerCall(), CanAnswerExecute);
        EndCommand = new CommandHandler(() => _model.HangUpCall(), CanHangupExecute);
    }

    private bool CanAnswerExecute()
    {
       return _model.CheckAction(ActionType.Answer);
    }

    private bool CanHangupExecute()
    {
        return _model.CheckAction(ActionType.Drop);
    }
}
```

**To the actual problem**
I have one call and it is correctly displayed on the UI.
After I click on the "EndCommand" button, the call dissapears from the UI (as expected)

The problem now is:
When i set a breakpoint in mehtod "CanAnswerExecute()", it will be reached, whenever i click on the UI.

I understand that, the "CommandManager" has a reference to every ICommand, and therefore to the ViewModel. But why doesn't this reference get removed, when my viewmodel, disappears from the list?

Answer (score 0):

just a hunch, did not try, try to change

```
public CommandHandler AnswerCommand { get; }
public CommandHandler EndCommand { get; }
```

for

```
public ICommand AnswerCommand { get; }
public ICommand EndCommand { get; }
```